# Intersection of two json files

Tags: javascript, json, intersection

I have two JSON arrays with same fields as follows:

```
var total_90 = [
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 1, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2012-11-14T16:30:43Z", "quantity": 3, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" }
];

var tip_0 = [
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 80, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 70, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" }
];
```

I need a third JSON file which has the intersection of the above two JSON files. (By intersection, I mean all the rows from both the JSON files which have *TOTAL=90* AND *TIP=0*)
Is there some way to do this?

My expected output will be a third JSON file with the following output

```
{"date":"2012-11-14T16:30:43Z","quantity":3,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T16:58:03Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T16:30:43Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"}
```

Comment: what would be your expected intersection output

Comment: added the expected output in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two json array object based on union and intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304104/merging-two-json-array-object-based-on-union-and-intersection)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function intersection(a, b)
{
  var result = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if (a[i].total == 90 && a[i].tip == 0)
            {

                result.push(a[i]);
            }
        }

       for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            if (b[i].total == 90 && b[i].tip == 0)
            {
                result.push(b[i]);
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/U52bs/)

**EDIT:** Update the function with the use of `concat` to provide a slightly more short hand.

```
function intersection(a, b)
{
  var result = [];

    var c = a.concat(b);


       for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            if (c[i].total == 90 && c[i].tip == 0)
            {

                result.push(c[i]);
            }
        }

    return result;
}
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/U52bs/1/)

Comment: can you take a look at this?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827030/cross-filter-using-drop-downs

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the 2 objects and merge the contents into 1 object.

For examples check this thread since this is a duplicate [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to collect all the rows from both the JSON files which have ***TOTAL = 90*** and ***TIP = 0*** -

```js
var total_90 = [
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 1, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2012-11-14T16:30:43Z", "quantity": 3, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" }
];

var tip_0 = [
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 80, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 70, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" },
    { "date": "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", "quantity": 2, "total": 90, "tip": 0, "type": "tab" }
];

// An empty arrays to contain final intersection array
var result = [];

/* now looping over both arrays to traverse all the elements from them */

// iterating over first array
total_90.forEach(x => {
    // iterating over second array
    tip_0.forEach(y => {
        // push into output array only if total is 90 & tip is 0
        if ((x.total == 90 && y.total == 90) && (x.tip == 0 && y.tip == 0)) {
            result.push({
                date: x.date,
                quantity: x.quantity,
                total: x.total,
                tip: x.tip,
                type: x.type
            });
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

**Note -** *this can be optimized to reduce the time complexity.*

Answer (score -1):

```
var total_90 = [
{"date":"2011-11-14T17:22:59Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T17:07:21Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":1,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2012-11-14T16:30:43Z","quantity":3,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"}
              ]

var tip_0 = [
{"date":"2011-11-14T17:22:59Z","quantity":2,"total":80,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T17:07:21Z","quantity":2,"total":70,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T16:58:03Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"},
{"date":"2011-11-14T16:30:43Z","quantity":2,"total":90,"tip":0,"type":"tab"}
            ] 

allData['total_90'] = total_90;
allData['tip_0'] = tip_0;
```

use `allData`

Comment: -1 This only gives an allData object with the 2 objects not the objects merged into 1.