# Cross-filter using drop downs

Tags: javascript, json, crossfilter

I have two drop-downs.
I want that whenever a selection is made in either of the drop-downs, a function called intersect be called which in turn calls the functions loadData and loadData1.My code is attached here.

```
<select onchange="intersect()" id="metric" class="wrapper-dropdown">
<option value ="190">190</option>
    <option value ="90">90</option>
    <option value ="100">100</option>
    <option value ="300">300</option>
</select>

<select onchange="intersect()" id="metric1" class="wrapper-dropdown">
<option value ="100">100</option>
    <option value ="200">200</option>
    <option value ="0">0</option>
</select>
<script>

var intersect= function() {

var total_90 = function() {
var data = [
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
 {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
 ];
 var ndx = crossfilter(data);
 var totalDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.total; });  
 var total_90 =     totalDim.filter(document.getElementById('metric').selectedOptions[0].value); 
return total_90;
  };
var tip_90 = function() {
var data = [
{date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
{date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
{date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
{date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
];
 var ndx = crossfilter(data);
 var tipDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.tip; });  
 var tip_90 = tipDim.filter(document.getElementById('metric1').selectedOptions[0].value); 
 return tip_90;
 }
 var result = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < total_90.length; i++){
        if (total_90[i].total == 90 && total_90[i].tip == 0)
        {

            result.push(total_90[i]);
        }
    }

   for (var i = 0; i < tip_90.length; i++){
        if (tip_90[i].total == 90 && tip_90[i].tip == 0)
        {
            result.push(tip_90[i]);
        }
    }
function print_filter(filter){
var f=eval(filter);
if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","   [\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
    } 
    print_filter("result"); 
     }
    </script>
    </body>
```

So, at any given instance if I select '90' in the first drop down and '0' is already selected in the second drop down,then I want all the rows from both the JSON arrays which have total=90 and tip=0 to be printed on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure why you want to use `d3.js` and `crossfilter.js` I do not see a need in your question.

Since you only tag `javascript` in your question. I am hereby provide you a pure JS solution instead of `jquery`

```
var m1 = document.getElementById('metric');

var m2 = document.getElementById('metric1');

m1.onchange = function(){
    //alert(m1.value);
    //alert(m2.value);
    var result = intersection(data, data1, m1.value, m2.value);

    if (result != ""){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            console.log(result[i]);
        }
    }   
}

m2.onchange = function(){

    var result = intersection(data, data1, m1.value, m2.value);

    if (result != ""){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            console.log(result[i]);
        }
    }
}

//a is the data
//b is the data1
//v1 is the metric value
//v2 is the matric1 value
function intersection(a, b, v1, v2)
{
    var result = [];
    var c = a.concat(b);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){

        if (c[i].total == v1 && c[i].tip == v2)
        {                             
            result.push(c[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/d6EcV/2/) try your selection with total = 90 and tip = 0. You will get the so call "intersection" result you want.

Comment: Why I need d3 and cross filter is because, I have to plot the values in graphical and tabular format which should change when either of the values in the drop down changes. Infact, there are quite a few more drop downs which are yet to be added. I am new to all of this coding and stuff.So, I am just playing around with all options that I see. Can you suggest anything better that can help me out in eventually plotting graph and table with drop downs?

Comment: use `d3.js` is not a bad idea for data visualization if you are using an up-to-date browser

Comment: Awesome.!!.I modified the code a little to add an extra drop down for the dataset to be selected.Again, I want that whenever either of the three filters change,the value should be printed to console.What am I doing wrong here? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vjLZ9/)

Comment: lol.. you cant do like that. The data is an array not an element.

Comment: I went through the tutorial. Doesn't have anything on how arrays linked with drop downs can be passed as a parameter to some other function. :(

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what's so difficult here...

> I want that whenever a selection is made in either of the drop-downs, a function called intersect be called which in turn calls the functions loadData and loadData1.

```
<select onchange="intersect()" id="metric" class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <option value ="190">190</option>
    <option value ="90">90</option>
    <option value ="100">100</option>
    <option value ="300">300</option>
</select>

<select onchange="intersect()" id="metric1" class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <option value ="100">100</option>
    <option value ="200">200</option>
    <option value ="0">0</option>
</select>
```

with

```
function loadData() {
    alert("loadData reached");
}
function loadData1() {
    alert("loadData1 reached");
}
function intersect() {
    loadData();    
    loadData1();
}
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/8vqG2/)

Comment: Yeah fine.!!.I'm also doing the same here.but I am getting a blank array as output for whatever selection I make.Help me fixing the code that I have posted,if you can

Comment: create a fiddle of your code. and post the link here, that way i could help you better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aBsS4/   However,this code requires d3.js and crossfilter.js to be included..I don't have any idea,how this can be done on fiddle.net